# Google search by image from own webpage

Tags: html, forms, google-image-search

Is it possible to search by an image directly from my own webpage?

i will like to insert an url like: "http://thegalaxyguide.com/galaxy/sun/ultra_violet_sun.gif" and then be redirected to google and watch the result.

i tried this

```
    <form method="get" action="http://images.google.com/searchbyimage"
    <input type="text" />
    <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </form>
```

but it is just going to googles own "search by image" page...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This does

```
<form method=get action='http://www.google.co.in/searchbyimage'>
<input type=text name=image_url value='https://www.google.com/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo3w.png'>
<input type=hidden name='encoded_image' value='' />
<input type=hidden name='image_content' value='' />
<input type=hidden name='filename' value='' />
<input type=hidden name='num' value='10' />
<input type=hidden name='hl' value='en' />
<input type=hidden name='authuser' value='0' />
<input type=hidden name='bih' value='638' />
<input type=hidden name='biw' value='1366' /><br>
<input type=submit name='biw' value='search' />
</form>
```